# some errors to start ReactNative with expo:is not valid sdk version

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I run bellow command to start my first application.

```
d:/reactnative/create-react-native-app weather --scripts-version 1.14.0
d:/reactnative/cd weather
d:/reactnative/weather/expo start
```

but it showed me this error in my device:

> something went wrong.
>   27.0.0 is not valid sdk version.
>   Options are 35.0.0, 34.0.0, 33.0.0,
>   UNVERSIONED

then I tried another:

```
d:/reactnative/expo init zarrinExpo
d:/reactnative/cd zarrinexpo
d:/reactnative/zarrinexpo/expo start
```

but I had that error again. so I run `expo update 35.0.0` then `expo start` showed me an error and said to me run `set EXPO_DEBUG=true` but there is that error(27.0.0 is not valid sdk version...).
then i tried these commands:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-native-app
npm i -g create-react-native-app
```

but  that error showed again.before this, I could run `react-native run-android` without error. but I am following new tutorial with expo.
can you guide me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try uninstalling the expo app from the device and reinstalling it?

Comment: why do you think install and reinstall expo can help me? i read this **Expo CLI replaces our previous tools exp (a CLI) and XDE (a desktop app)** and i run
`yarn global add expo-cli` last week.

Comment: Reinstalling it on the emulator takes 1 minute and you can always try it. I had some weird errors in React Native so far and reinstalling was not a official fix but when i did it it worked. it was just something that you can try i am not saying that its the fix^^ good luck